# Can't apply bootstrap to react (type is invalid)

Tags: react-bootstrap

I can't apply Bootstrap to my project.

```
import {Button, Form, Label, Input, Modal, ModalBody} from 'react- 
bootstrap';
```

In my index.html I have a link to CDN.
I am confused because import worked in very similar project but with another imported components.

```
My render method 
render() {
      return (
        <div>
        ...
        <Modal name='modal' isOpen={this.state.showModal}> 
          <ModalBody>
             Please add a popup for a location.
              <Form name="form">
            <Label for="Popup">Popup</Label>
            <Input type="text" name="popup" id="popup" placeholder="Popup"/> 
            <Button bsStyle="primary" type="submit"
            onClick={(e)=>this.submit(e)}>Add</Button>
             </Form>
         </ModalBody></Modal>
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
```

My imports to MapComponent component

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import {Button,  Form, Label,  Input, Modal, ModalBody} from 'react- 
     bootstrap';
import { Map, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from 'react-leaflet'
```

My imports to the App component

```
import 'babel-polyfill';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route, hashHistory } from 'react-router';
import MapComponent from './MapComponent.jsx';
import styles from '../../css/styles.css';
```

Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `MapComponent`.
    in MapComponent (created by RouterContext)
    in RouterContext (created by Router)
    in Router (created by App)
    in App

Comment: Can you also post what you are importing in this file?

Comment: Your Update Section saved the day! The problem was that I was confused with reactstrap and bootstrap. Changing all to one style made it work! THANK YOU for providing me your guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `CDN` link you cannot import modules like,

```
import {Button, Form, Label, Input, Modal, ModalBody} from 'react- 
bootstrap';
```

You need to install `react-bootstrap`.

```
npm install react-bootstrap --save
```

or

```
yarn add react-bootstrap
```

**Update**

You are importing `{Button, Form, Label, Input, Modal, ModalBody}` from `react-bootstrap` but you are using `reactstrap` code for your modal,

```
import {Button, Form, Label, Input, Modal, ModalBody} from 'react-bootstrap';
```

This is code for [`reactstrap`](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/modals/) modal

```
<Modal name='modal' isOpen={this.state.showModal}> 
          <ModalBody>
             Please add a popup for a location.
              <Form name="form">
            <Label for="Popup">Popup</Label>
            <Input type="text" name="popup" id="popup" placeholder="Popup"/> 
            <Button bsStyle="primary" type="submit"
            onClick={(e)=>this.submit(e)}>Add</Button>
             </Form>
         </ModalBody></Modal>
```

You can change your import to make your code work

```
import {Button, Form, Label, Input, Modal, ModalBody} from 'reactstrap';
```

OR

If you want to use [`react-bootstrap`](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/) modal then this is the code for modal

```
<Modal.Dialog>
  <Modal.Header closeButton>
    <Modal.Title>Modal title</Modal.Title>
  </Modal.Header>

  <Modal.Body>
    <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
  </Modal.Body>

  <Modal.Footer>
    <Button variant="secondary">Close</Button>
    <Button variant="primary">Save changes</Button>
  </Modal.Footer>
</Modal.Dialog>
```

Comment: also post your `package.json` file.

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "leaflet": "^1.5.1",
    "mongodb": "^2.2.6",
    "react-leaflet": "^1.9.1",
    "reactstrap": "^8.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.5",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.13.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
    "css-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.10.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.1",
    "react-router": "^3.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "webpack": "^1.13.2",
  },

Comment: update your question with your component code where you are getting this error.

Comment: In a folder 'static' I've created a file named bootstrap with content '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist' and with a link to CDN it worked well. I mean, in my previous project.

Comment: We cannot help by just reading the explanation, show your code. Also the error clearly saying that you missed exporting something.